# Prevent IllegalStateException in SQLiteCursor for Android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-cursor

I have an `ListActivity` that is bound to a cursor, when items in the `ListView` are selected an `EditItem` activity is launched by `startActivityForResult`, this `EditItem` activity preforms several queries, each placed in their own separate Cursor.  These are used to populate spinners, much like a lookup field in an Access DB.

My issue is that once the user leaves this `EditItem` activity, either via submit, cancel or back button, goes back to the `ListView` Activity and selects another entry in the `ListView` (same item or a different one) I get `IllegalStateException` errors in my `SQLiteCursor` class (Android's, not mine).  I **am** closing my cursors in the `onDestroy` method of **both** activities, since sometimes calling for a result will still destroy the calling activity.

This does not always occur on the second selection of an Item, sometimes it will occur on the third selection.  I thought maybe I was just moving faster than the OS, so I starting pausing, up to 30 seconds, between my actions, the error is only thrown after calling the activity for result a second or third time.  No amount of pausing fixes this.

**Edit:** The error is in the `SQLiteCursor finalize` method at the call to `super.finalize();`

**Edit #2:** Stack trace for thread:

```
Daemon System Thread [<5> HeapWorker] (Suspended (exception IllegalStateException)) 
SQLiteCursor.finalize() line: 603   
NativeStart.run() line: not available [native method]
```

**Edit #3** Stack trace from LogCat (partslist is the table name):

```
INFO/dalvikvm(599): Ljava/lang/IllegalStateException;: Finalizing cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@437541a0 on partslist that has not been deactivated or closed
INFO/dalvikvm(599):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.finalize(SQLiteCursor.java:596)
INFO/dalvikvm(599):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

Comment: @Timbermar: The only place `SQLiteCursor` throws `IllegalStateException` has nothing to do with `finalize()`, based on the source code, so it is difficult to give you advice. Use `StrictMode` in an Android 2.3 environment to perhaps help you debug this. In the future, consider including the relevant portion of the stack trace in your questions.

Comment: @CommonsWare: I only mentioned it as to indicate that it wasn't an issue running the queries, it seems to be caused by my cursors not be correctly disposed of.  Also, I forgot to mention I use `startManagingCursor` as well, when I create the cursors.  Also, I added the stack, all 3 lines of it.  This error is not occurring in the main thread, but a separate thread so the app continues to run even as this crashes.

Comment: @Timbermar: That is not a stack trace. That is Eclipse telling you it intercepted an exception. Let processing continue, and you will get a stack trace in the LogCat pane of the DDMS perspective.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Stack trace is pretty similar from Logcat, it never makes it into a full blown error or shut down of app.  I've added it to the question.

Comment: @Timbermar: All I can tell you is, that exception does not lie. Somewhere, you missed a `Cursor`.

Comment: @CommonsWare: I agree, your right, I've just been looking at this for way to long.  I totally forgot about **two** other cursors I create (in order to set the spinners to the correct position [shown here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559611/setselection-on-spinner-based-on-rowid/2560990#2560990)) that were buried deep in the onCreate.  Thanks for your help.  As soon as you mentioned it I went looking for them.  I think this is why I should stop coding on Saturdays.  Thanks again.  I wish you'd made that an answer, so I could have selected it.

Answer (score 16):

Make sure you `cursor.close()` when finished with them.