# How can I get the position of a row in a dataset in order to set the selected item in an Android Spinner?

Tags: android, cursor, spinner, selecteditem

I have a Spinner that's populated using a cursor containing data from a database.  It appears that it's impossible to set the selected item in the spinner using the value of the ID column of a row.  And that the only way to set the selected item is by using the *position* of the row within the dataset.  Is this correct?  If so, is there a more efficient way of determining the row's position than by iterating through the dataset using the cursor?

The inefficient (to my mind) way is outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559611/setselection-on-spinner-based-on-rowid).

Thanks much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step, create view for your data set, with joins etc.:

```
CREATE VIEW my_view AS
  SELECT _id, field FROM my_table
```

Second step:

```
CREATE VIEW my_view2 AS
  SELECT count(*) AS row_id, q1.*
  FROM my_view AS q1
  LEFT JOIN my_view AS q2
  WHERE q1._id >= q2._id
  GROUP BY q1._id
```

Then simply:

```
SELECT * FROM my_view2
```

Results:

```
row_id | _id | field

1   4   XbMCmUBFwb
2   6   Te JMejSaK
3   8   dDGMMiuRuh
4   10  phALAbnq c
5   11  EQQwPKksIj
6   12  PAt tbDnf
7   13  f zUSuhvM
8   14  TIMBgAGhkT
9   15  OOcnjKLLER
```

To get position by id:

```
SELECT * FROM my_view2 WHERE _id=11
```

Results:

```
row_id | _id | field

5   11  EQQwPKksIj
```

Hope that help

Comment: Great solution. It didn't occur to me that I could solve this on the database side. Thanks much.